# Django / Apache returns HTTP 500 Randomly

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I have been dealing with a rather strange issue lately. My backend has httpd + mod wsgi + Django setup.

I have a class-based view as follows:

```
class ExtrasView(View):

def get(self, request):
    path = settings.BASE_DIR + "/data.json"
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The get request to the above view works perfectly 9 out of 10 times. However, randomly this view would give a response with status 500. Based on the apache log, it seems that the response body length is correct i.e. the length of data in the file. This is verified by apache access logs.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? I have checked the error logs and there's nothing in the errorlog. The error log does print tracebacks in case of exceptions or other syntax errors, just in this case it doesn't print anything so I'm clueless. Needless to say, the file being read is a static file that 100% exists.

The data in the file is huge, it's length is about 30-40k characters. Would this cause an issue? If yes, then why does it work 9 out of 10 times?

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: If it's a static file why not serve it like other static files?

Comment: @IainShelvington as ultimately I would like to add some logic to manipulate the json before sending the response.

Comment: Does the file need to be json? Could you not store the resulting object in a .py file or as a constant in your view module?

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea, especially considering the length of the JSON as I mentioned in my post. Also, the code presented is a bare-bones function which causes a problem, if I'm able to fix this I would have multiple files and I would read one of them based on a get parameter.

Comment: Why does the length matter? You're already reading the file into memory. The performance of your view would increase drastically if you were not reading and parsing the file every request

Comment: It would just make managing the content difficult when the number of files increases. Imaging about 20 constants in a .py file with that length. Individual files are way easy to manage I think. Do you think reading the file is an issue in my code and can throw 500 randomly which doesn't show any exceptions in the errorlog?

Comment: If you're planning on having 20 files like this an need to manipulate the data why not store the data in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just return the json file directly instead of loading it as json and returning it. Something like

```
def get(self, request)
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return Response(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could do that. However, ultimately I would like to add some logic to manipulate the json before sending the response so I would like to keep this approach. Do you see a problem where my code could return 500 if the file is present and has valid json data?

Comment: i see, yes it might be the case that the file is still being read / locked by one request and another is already requesting it. Consider caching the file in memory if it is being opened quite frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In case the file is being read / locked by another request - wouldn't it throw an error instead of responding with HTTP 500 and the body content?

Comment: i'm not an expert with apache, so i couldn't completely answer that. perhaps log your python aswel, and see if the error is python or apache